# setOnItemClickListener is not working with listView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have one nested ListView inside the LinearLayout. Because I wanted to add one slider at the top of ListView.

Following is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listViewLinearLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--    SliderView-->
    <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
        app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderIndicatorEnabled="true"
        app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
        app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
        app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
        app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1" />

<ListView
     android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to set OnItemClickListener on ListView. So that when we click on any listItem we can show another activity.

For that I wrote this JAVA code :

```
CardAdapter cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(this,cards);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

        // Setting listener to ListView
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("GetIntent","PLace Name =");

                Card card = cards.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(HistoricActivity.this,HistoricDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("MyClass", (Serializable) card);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I also print some logs inside the OnItemClickListener for debug purposes.

So the problem is it's not working.

In my previous project when I did it. It looks like this :
[here `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` is highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow11D.png)

But now in this :
[`new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`  is not getting highlighted by Android Studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxFP8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your buttons (or any other views you want to handle click inside a list item) like this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: I updated the qustion please check the following photos also.